# написал телеграм бот на питоне но после хостинга сайт не отправляет фоток

Tags: python, telebot, pythonanywhere

Есть фотографии на пк, нужно сделать так, чтобы они отправлялись в телеграм бот (Бот задеплоин на pythonanywhere).Бот написан на Python. Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать базу данных для отправки фото,. Объясните пожалуйста как вообще можно "переправить" фото, ну или каким принципом это все делается

Answer (score 0):

Фото залей на хостинг и путь поменяй если нужно.

Comment: я загрузил фото в хостинг, но не понимаю как написать путь!

Comment: Добавь фото в директорию со своим скриптом и где нужно прописать путь -просто напиши название файла(картинки)